# Bbox malfunction on both axis

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a test for a Tkinter project, which will have some mini-games in the software (sort of like Mario paint). For this test, I have 2 boxes, one colored red and the other is blue but when it is next to or inside the red box it turns green.

Here is the code.

```py
from tkinter import *
from threading import Timer

window = Tk()
window.title("Canvas Test")

x = 30
y = 30

Test = Canvas(window, width = 1000, height = 1000)
Test.config(bg = "white")
Test.pack()

Move = Test.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 40, y + 40, fill = "blue")
Hitd = Test.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 40, y + 40, fill = "red")
Move = Test.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 30, y + 30, fill = "blue")

Test.update()

w = False
a2 = False
s = False
d = False

def KeyDown(event):
    print("K Down")
    global x
    global y
    global Move
    global w
    global a2
    global s
    global d
    if event.char == "w" or event.char == "W":
        w = True
    elif event.char == "s" or event.char == "S":
        s = True
    if event.char == "a" or event.char == "A":
        a2 = True 
    elif event.char == "d" or event.char == "D":
        d = True

def KeyUp(event):
    print("K Up")
    global w
    global a2
    global s
    global d
    if event.char == "w" or event.char == "W":
        w = False
    elif event.char == "s" or event.char == "S":
        s = False
    if event.char == "a" or event.char == "A":
        a2 = False 
    elif event.char == "d" or event.char == "D":
        d = False


def MoveCheck():
    global Move
    global w
    global a2
    global s
    global d
    if w == True:
        Test.move(Move, 0, -10) #name, x mod, y mod
    elif s == True:
        Test.move(Move, 0, 10)
    if a2 == True:
        Test.move(Move, -10, 0)
    elif d == True:
        Test.move(Move, 10, 0)

    a = Test.bbox(Move)
    b = Test.bbox(Hitd)
    if b[0] in range(a[0],a[2]) or b[2] in range(a[0],a[2]) and b[1] in range(a[1],a[3]) or b[3] in range(a[1],a[3]):
        Test.itemconfig(Move, fill = "green")
    else:
        Test.itemconfig(Move, fill = "blue")

    t = Timer(0.03, MoveCheck)
    t.start()
MoveCheck()

window.bind("<Key>", KeyDown)
window.bind("<KeyRelease>", KeyUp)

window.mainloop()
```

If you get in-line with the block and then move 1 down or up (or left/right depending on what axis you are testing this on) then you will see that the block turns green anyway. I am extremely new to using bbox, so it might just be an oversight on my part.

Comment: maybe try [Canvas.find_overlapping](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method) to test if one rectangle overlap other rectangle

Comment: you can use `root.after(30, MoveCheck)` instead of `Thread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Canvas.find_overlapping()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method)
 to test if moving rectangle overlaps other objects.

```
a = Test.bbox(Move)
#b = Test.bbox(Hitd)

if Hitd in Test.find_overlapping(*a):
    Test.itemconfig(Move, fill = "green")
else:
    Test.itemconfig(Move, fill = "blue")
```

---

Full working code with other changes

- `after()` instead of `Thread`
- `lower_case_names` for variables ([PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))
- without spaces around `=` in arguments in functions ([PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))
- without `import *` ([PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))
- all functions (and classes) before main part
- variable names which means something (`canvas` instead of `Test`)

.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def key_down(event):
    global speed_x
    global speed_y

    print("K Down")

    char = event.char.lower()

    if char == "w":
        speed_y = -10
    elif char == "s":
        speed_y = 10
    elif char == "a":
        speed_x = -10
    elif char == "d":
        speed_x = 10

def key_up(event):
    global speed_x
    global speed_y

    print("K Up")

    char = event.char.lower()

    if char in ("w", "s"):
        speed_y = 0
    elif char in ("a", "d"):
        speed_x = 0


def move_check():
    canvas.move(player, speed_x, speed_y) #name, x mod, y mod

    player_bbox = canvas.bbox(player)

    if enemy in canvas.find_overlapping(*player_bbox):
        canvas.itemconfig(player, fill="green")
    else:
        canvas.itemconfig(player, fill="blue")

    window.after(30, move_check)

# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Canvas Test")

x = 30
y = 30
speed_x = 0
speed_y = 0

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=1000, height=1000, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

enemy = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+40, y+40, fill="red")
player = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+30, y+30, fill="blue")

move_check()

window.bind("<Key>", key_down)
window.bind("<KeyRelease>", key_up)

window.mainloop()
```